# React Redux: Why is this nested component not receiving props from redux state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've got a parent component `Course` that is able to get state from redux and I'm able to log that out successfully:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import SchoolWrapper from "../SchoolWrapper";

export class Course extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("Props in course", props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <SchoolWrapper>Wrapped component</SchoolWrapper>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.user,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Course);
```

Nested in the `Course` component is another component `SchoolWrapper` that is able to get props from redux state:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Nav } from "./Student/Nav";

export class SchoolWrapper extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("SchoolWrapper props", props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Nav />
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.user,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SchoolWrapper);
```

However, the `Nav` component or any other component nested at this level is not able to access state from redux.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";


import { connect } from "react-redux";

export class Nav extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("Nav props: ", props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        nav goes here...
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.user,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Nav);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think you're importing Nav wrong... ```export default connect...```, then you try to `import { Nav } ...`.  It should be `import Nav from "./Student/Nav"`.

Comment: Oh yeah, that was it. Thank you so much. If interested in adding an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: uh sure, I'll take it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're importing Nav wrong, here you're using a "default" export:

```js
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Nav);
```

But you try to use a "named" import:

```js
import { Nav } from "./Student/Nav";
```

`Nav` should be imported as a "default":

```js
import Nav from "./Student/Nav"
```